# Storing dynamic form in a model

Tags: python, django-forms

I want to build a system using Django that will allow users to build forms, store them and have their customers use them. I know how I can go about creating the forms dynamically but I'm looking for a good way to still use the form classes and handle many different user's dynamic forms in an elegant way.

I'm thinking of storing the form field information as a dictionary in the db. Is there any way in django to re-interpret this dictionary back into a form object? Or do I have to write a routine that will simply interpret and build out a form in html myself?

If someone knows where to point me to the info I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Python question more than a Django question, whence my tag edit.

To reproduce the equivalent of, say:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    foo = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

you need something like:

```
f = type(forms.Form)('MyForm', forms.Form, d)
```

where `d` is a dictionary like:

```
d = { 'foo': forms.CharField(max_length=100) }
```

Of course, in the end the form class will be bound to name `f` (you can use `setattr` to bind it to **qualified** name `something.MyForm` for an appropriate `something`, but **please** don't even dream of binding it to a **bare** name that's dynamically variables -- it would also be a nightmare to **use** such a barename!).

So, to recreate the form class object at runtime, you need to preserve:

1. its name `MyForm`
2. a dict with the field names as keys and the field objects as values

and to make point 2 work, you similarly need to preserve for each field (besides its name) the *type* name (so you can recover the type with a `getattr` from `forms`) and its named parameters (as a dict), so you can basically do

d[fieldname] = getattr(forms, fieldtypename)(**fieldparameters)

based on strings `fieldname` and `fieldtypename` and dict `fieldparameters`, for each field, as you rebuild dictionary `d` (i.e., prepare to satisfy step 2 of the above short list;-).

Comment: You can also pickle objects and store them in the database. However, I think you may run into issues as Alex hints with varying names.

Comment: Thanks! I actually did more digging after posting the question and found a good article on how to do this using django,James Bennett's Dynamic form article.

Comment: From James article you should refer to forms.BaseForm rather than forms.Form

Comment: f = type(forms.Form)('MyForm', forms.Form, d) becomes                 f = type(forms.Form)('MyForm', forms.BaseForm, d)